# How good are dentists in the United Kingdom?

Tags: uk, health

Bit OT perhaps, but I'm toying with the idea to travel abroad to have some dental work done.  I'm not after cheap... I'm not after the very best (though I'd like it to be good)... I'm after *painless* - I suffer from more than a bit phobia when it comes to dentists.

The United Kingdom - probably in or around London - seems to be an obvious choice for me location-vise, so I have a few questions:

- How expensive are British dentists?  Are they part of the national health-care scheme?  As a foreigner I'll have to pay cash, so how much would it cost for say... pulling a tooth?  a root-canal...  fixing a cavety...?
- Do they use dinitro-oxide (N2O - ie. "laughing gas") or similar?  (Dentists in my country sadly does not.)
- How "good" are they?  How good work do they do?  I ask because I've heard a few less then complementary jokes about British dentists...

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE.  While it may be somewhat on-topic if you need dental care abroad but you're asking of costs and possibly licenses, which will vary from dentist to dentist.  Not to mention that the question of "good" is too subjective to ask without a strict definition

Comment: I suggest you find dentist listings in the UK, could be done easily using google or google maps. Then email few of them and you will get a more accurate and detailed answer.

Comment: You need to only ask single objective questions, though we don't mind if it has a side question or bonus question or if the single objective question is illustrated with minor questions. But in this case your main question is subjective because obviously there are excellent and terrible dentists in the UK. Now your two sub questions are objective but you need to ask them separately one at a time.

Comment: If you want to go to UK to use dentist it's not a travel question. But it could be on-topic on Expatriates proposal: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38732/expatriates